# How to lookup an multiple datas and return respective data from the Lookup location.Also what are other faster alternatives to VLOOKUP in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

How can i lookup all the data's from *LOOKUP DATA* and return the "House" data from *LOOKUP LOCATION*.I used following code but its slow and it simply pastes the array formula on cell.

```
.Cells(12 + i, 3).FormulaArray = "=INDEX($G:$G,MATCH(B4 & C4 & D4,$H:$H & $I:$I & $J:$J,0))"
```

Other ideas that i have in mind is to **Concatenate** the *LOOKUP DATA* & *LOOKUP LOCATION* and then use **LOOKUP** to get the respective data.

- **Are there any faster approach for looking up multiple data's using VBA ?**

Comment: See [DGET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dget-function-455568bf-4eef-45f7-90f0-ec250d00892e?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60283&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the required code..I have used array rather than range which is faster..You can adjust outer loop if you need to find more than 3..Check this out.It's working for me..

```
Public Sub MultipleMatch()
Dim arr As Variant, arr2 As Variant, i As Byte, j As Long
With Sheets("Sheet4")
arr = .Range("G4:J" & .Cells(1048576, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Value
arr2 = .Range("B4:D6").Value
For i = 1 To 3
    For j = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(j, 2) = arr2(i, 1) And arr(j, 3) = arr2(i, 2) And arr(j, 4) = arr2(i, 3) Then
            .Cells(i + 13, 2).Value = arr(j, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End With
End Sub
```